# Symfony2 Form EntityType Datagrid view

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, datagrid

Using Symfony2, is it possible to display an EntityType as a datagrid type of view?  I want the user to be presented the data view so they can see other properties other than what I would jam into the __toString() method. The datagrid would best be displayed with a checkbox at the beginning of the row to allow one or more to be selected. (multiple = true)

Answer (score 1):

Symfony has no such functionality out of the box.

You can either [extend](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) EntityType and define a separate template for each entity you have, or you can make your app based on [SonataAdminBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/index.html), which has a lot of features to make grids.

Comment: Extending the entitytype might be a great idea. I do have SonataAdminBundle included in my project but I don't want to use their "interface" rather want everything obviously in my own layout. Can their functionality be used in my own controllers and forms? Only way I've used it so far is just adding my entities to the config file then goi g to the admin path and using it that way.